# позиционирование шестиугольника и border

Tags: html, css

Здравствуйте. Есть у меня шестиугольник и по нему у меня несколько вопросов   (**шестиугольник**) www.jsfiddle.net/m00qot3L/ 
Во-первых о позиционировании. Находится он в бутстраповском контейнере. Используя margin 0 auto он не никак не хочет выравниваться по центру. Я исспользовал flex контейнер и выровнял контент по центру. Можно так сделать? Просто вся эта конитель с кросбраузерностью....

Во-вторых нужно шестиугольнику задать границу. Я её задал, но то что получилось ... Как сделать её цельной т.е. без промежутков?

Comment: Нужен вариант именно html? Возможно, стоит использовать svg

Comment: Беда в том что я о нём ничего не знаю. Значит буду разбираться в нём. Скажите эту секцию тоже стоит делать в SVG https://habrastorage.org/files/a31/813/204/a31813204ab3400bb46d51eeb2770794.jpg но я понятия не имею как его адаптивить

Comment: svg - это тоже разметка, основанная на XML, сложные визуальные элементы, вроде линейных графиков и пр. обычно реализуют с помощью svg. Это не сложнее, чем html, к тегам svg также можно применять стилизацию через CSS, только они имеют свои свойства. Документацию по svg можно найти тут https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/SVG

Если предполагается, что вёрстка будет не резиновой, а статичной, то можно красные контуры для шестиугольников сделать просто изображением и наложить через background: url();

Comment: Спасибо =) Я на сайт мозилы попал и читаю сейчас. Еще вот такое руководство нашел http://css-live.ru/articles/karmannoe-rukovodstvo-po-napisaniyu-svg-glava-1-organizaciya-dokumenta.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**по моему svg можно хоть как применить , может кривовато но как вариант подходит**

```css
*{margin:0; padding:0;}
.svg_elem{
  display:table;
  margin:30px auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="svg_elem">
<svg style="width:250px;height:250px;">
<polygon 
points=
      "10 160,
       10 80,
       80 10,
       175 10,
       240 80,
       240 160,
       170 240,
       70 240
       "
style="fill: yellow; fill-opacity:0.5; stroke-width:3px;stroke: black;" />
</svg>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо. буду копать в этом направлении. Потому что мне делать еще это https://hsto.org/files/a31/813/204/a31813204ab3400bb46d51eeb2770794.jpg Кстати можно с помощью SVG так линию провести?

Comment: можно так как на скрине , но лично я не смогу это сделать адаптивно ,.

Answer (score 1):

Кроссбраузерный вариант, псевдоэлемент через `:` для старых браузеров, через `::` для новых. Конечно с толщиной обводки придется повозиться, думаю вы разберетесь, в примере рассчитывал значения для обводки в `2px`

```css
.hex {
  width: 100px;
  height: 55px;
  background: red;
  position: relative;
  margin: 50px;
}
.hex:before,
.hex::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: -25px;
  left: 0;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-left: 50px solid transparent;
  border-right: 50px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 25px solid red;
}
.hex:after,
.hex::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -25px;
  left: 0;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-left: 50px solid transparent;
  border-right: 50px solid transparent;
  border-top: 25px solid red;
}
.inner-hex {
  width: 96px;
  height: 55px;
  background: green;
  position: relative;
  margin: 50px 2px;
}
.inner-hex:before,
.inner-hex::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: -23px;
  left: 0;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-left: 48px solid transparent;
  border-right: 48px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 23px solid green;
}
.inner-hex:after,
.inner-hex::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -23px;
  left: 0;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-left: 48px solid transparent;
  border-right: 48px solid transparent;
  border-top: 23px solid green;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="hex">
  <div class="inner-hex"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Еще как вариант

[can i use](http://caniuse.com/#search=clip-path)

```css
.hex {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  background-color: #f00;
  position: relative;
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(50% 0%, 100% 25%, 100% 75%, 50% 100%, 0% 75%, 0% 25%);
  clip-path: polygon(50% 0%, 100% 25%, 100% 75%, 50% 100%, 0% 75%, 0% 25%);
  transition: 0.3s;
}
.hex-inner {
  position: absolute;
  top: 4px;
  left: 4px;
  right: 4px;
  bottom: 4px;
  background: #ccc;
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(50% 0%, 100% 25%, 100% 75%, 50% 100%, 0% 75%, 0% 25%);
  clip-path: polygon(50% 0%, 100% 25%, 100% 75%, 50% 100%, 0% 75%, 0% 25%);
}

.hex:hover{
  background: #00f;
}
```

```html
<div class="hex">
  <span class="hex-inner"></span>
</div>
```